# User Relationships view showing each relationship more than once

Tags: views, users

I'm trying to display a users relationships through Views(3). I'm getting duplicates for accepted relationships. Also, the current user show's up under his/her own relationships. Here's what I got so far:

---

*Format*: Unformatted list
*Show*: Fields

**Fields**
*User*: Name
*User*: Picture

**Filter criteria**
*User*: Active (Yes)
(rtid) *User relationships*: Requester or Requestee is current user (True)

**Sort criteria**
*User*: Created date (desc)

*Block name*: None
*Access*: Permission | View user profiles

**Contextual filters**
*User relationships*: Requester user  // I've tried (rtid) here with the same result

**Relationships**
*User relationships*: Requestee user
*User relationships*: Requester user
*User relationships*: RTID

*Use AJAX*:Yes

Comment: a good example for adding a user relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude current user from view by passing argument of current logged in user id and check exclude this argument from view.

You can avoid duplicates by enable distinct in basic settings.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  But, in views 3 I can't get a user:current under filters or contextual filters.  Also, I don't see an option for enable distinct anywhere in fields, filters, or contextual filters.

Comment: NM, figured it out.  Found the Distinct under Query settings.  Then, under fields I set User:Current(No).  This excluded the current user.  Would this be a good way of doing it though?  Cause I couldn't find exclude current user under contextual filters.  The closest I found was User:UID Exception Value.  But, I wasn't sure what to pass as the argument.